# QTabWidget how to hide pane only?

Tags: qt, qt4, qtabwidget

I have added a `QToolButton` as corner widget in `QTabWidget` which is checkable. I want to hide all tabs (panes only) when the tool button is unchecked. I tried to connect button's signal `clicked(bool)` with all tab's `setVisible(bool)` slot not working but. I also connected tabwidget's `setvisible` to the signal but complete widget became invisible(it was a silly trial). Is there any way to make only pane invisible and tab bar will not disappear ?

---

Edit: Code (ui have a tabwidget and two tabs namely tab and tab_2)

```
ui->setupUi(this);
QToolButton * b = new QToolButton;
b->setCheckable(true);
b->setChecked(true);
b->setAutoRaise(true);
b->setText("Hide Tabs");
ui->tabWidget->setCornerWidget(b);
connect(b,SIGNAL(clicked()),ui->tab,SLOT(hide()));
connect(b,SIGNAL(clicked()),ui->tab_2,SLOT(hide()));
```

Comment: What do you mean for the former experiment that it did not work? Did you get any warning on the console about the connect syntax? Mind pasting the code how you connected them? It should work, so we would need to see your code and console output when testing to proceed.

Comment: Could you please paste the relevant code? Refer to sscee.org for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my take on this. I've created a class that inherits QTabWidget. What I do is; set the "maximum vertical size of QTabWidget" to its `tabBar`s height to hide the panels.

It is a hacky solution and I had to add some extra lines to deal with quirks.

*file: hidabletabwidget.h*

---

```
#ifndef HIDABLETABWIDGET_H
#define HIDABLETABWIDGET_H

#include <QTabWidget>
#include <QAction>

class HidableTabWidget : public QTabWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit HidableTabWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    QAction hideAction;

private slots:
    void onHideAction(bool checked);
    void onTabBarClicked();
};

#endif // HIDABLETABWIDGET_H
```

*file: hidablewidget.cpp*

---

```
#include "hidabletabwidget.h"
#include <QTabBar>
#include <QToolButton>

HidableTabWidget::HidableTabWidget(QWidget *parent) :
    QTabWidget(parent),
    hideAction("▾", this)
{
    hideAction.setCheckable(true);
    hideAction.setToolTip("Hide Panels");
    QToolButton* hideButton = new QToolButton();
    hideButton->setDefaultAction(&hideAction);
    hideButton->setAutoRaise(true);
    this->setCornerWidget(hideButton);

    connect(&hideAction, SIGNAL(toggled(bool)), this, SLOT(onHideAction(bool)));
    connect(this, SIGNAL(tabBarClicked(int)), this, SLOT(onTabBarClicked()));
}

void HidableTabWidget::onHideAction(bool checked)
{
    if (checked)
    {
        this->setMaximumHeight(this->tabBar()->height());
        this->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Minimum);
    }
    else
    {
        this->setMaximumHeight(QWIDGETSIZE_MAX); // by default widgets can expand to a maximum sized defined by this macro
        this->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
    }
}

void HidableTabWidget::onTabBarClicked()
{
    hideAction.setChecked(false);
}
```

To use this, you can simply "promote" your QTabWidget to "HidableTabWidget" using qt designer.

And here is how it looks on my system:

[image: hidable widget shown and hidden states screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

Use `qFindChild` to find the `QTabBar` within the `QTabWidget`:

```
QTabBar *tabBar = qFindChild<QTabBar *>(ui->tabWidget);
tabBar->hide();
```

For Qt5:

```
QTabBar *tabBar = ui->tabWidget->findChild<QTabBar *>();
tabBar->hide();
```

Comment: This worked for me, however on Qt5 you should use `ui->tabWidget->findChild<QTabBar *>();` instead of `qFindChild` which is deprecated

Answer (score 2):

I can not comment due to my low "reputation" so far. If I could I'd just add a comment to Anatoli's answer: the goal is to hide "page area", not "tab bar". So if we imply they always use QStackedWidget for that then the answer should be more like:

```
auto * tab_pane = qFindChild<QStackedWidget *>(ui->tabWidget);
tab_pane->hide();
```

or for Qt5:

```
auto * tab_pane = ui->tabWidget->findChild<QStackedWidget *>();
tab_pane->hide();
```

Answer (score 2):

so I understand it like this, you want to hide the TabBar and let the tab visible. Or at least that's what I get from your question

Well if that the case all you have to do it's this:

```
connect(ui->pushButton,SIGNAL(clicked()),ui->tabWidget->tabBar(),SLOT(hide()));
```

I hope this was helpful, even do the questions in a little old, I though it may help new viewers.

Comment: Hides the tabBar succesfully (tested in pyqt5).

Answer (score 1):

You usually want to remove the Tab from the [QTabWidget](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtabwidget.html#removeTab):

```
void QTabWidget::removeTab ( int index )
```

The Tab removed will not be deleted and can be reinserted!
So you would connect your `QToolButton b` to a slot which simply removes the Tabs like this:

```
connect( b, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(hideTabs() );
..
void Foobar::hideTabs( void )
{
   for( int i = 0; i < ui->tabWidget->count(); ++i )
      ui->tabWidget->removeTab(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also cannot comment yet, I would just like to add that @HeyYO 's trick works and is the only way I could find to make it work.

I would add that in my example I wanted more flexibility on where to put the 'hide button' and what it should loo like.

So for that you would probably need some Layout. Wrap your Layout in QWidget to allow for changing the size settings and then do the same trick @HeyYO did, set maximum height of the Layout Widget.

Here is the Python code for the 'hide button':

```
@QtCore.pyqtSlot()
def on_settingsToggleButton_clicked(self):
    if self.settingsToggled:
        self.settingToggleContext = { 'max_height': self.settingsHlay.maximumHeight() }
        self.settingsHlay.setMaximumHeight(self.settingTabs.tabBar().height())
        self.settingsToggleButton.setIcon(up_icon)
    else:
        self.settingsHlay.setMaximumHeight(self.settingToggleContext['max_height'])
        self.settingsToggleButton.setIcon(down_icon)

    self.settingsToggled = not self.settingsToggled
```

This is my Qt Designer and how it looked
[image: Qt designer]

[image: not collapsed]      [image: collapsed]